# How does jQuery handle elements that don't exist on a page?

Tags: jquery

I have kind of a theory question on what happens when you have jQuery searching for elements/binding to elements that do not exist on a page.

For example, I have a javascript file that contains many Click events, however on some pages, those click events aren't used.  Rather than making multiple javascript files and having duplicate code, I have minified most of my code down to one file.

```
$('#target').click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Basically to sum up my paragraph into a few simple sentences.  What happens when id "target" doesn't exist?  How does jquery handle a case like this?

Now, whenever I work on my website, it seems like FireFox's memory usage grows like crazy.  Not sure if this is just FireFox or not, but if I don't have element on the page, is this causing memory leaks by binding to elements that don't exist?

Just curious what happens behind the scene.

Thanks!

Comment: *"What happens when id "target" doesn't exist?"* The same thing that happens when you iterate an empty Array. Nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no elements match your selector, you'll get an empty jQuery object (one that contains no elements).
Calling any method except `live()` on an empty jQuery object will do nothing at all and will not waste resources.

Comment: What happens when you do have a jQuery method that is live?  I do have a few of those as well for ajax checking...  Thanks for the initial knowledge though :)

Comment: @user1110302: Calling `live()` will add the selector and handler method to the global list of live events, in case a matching element appears in the future.  That's the whole point of `live()`.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: The object is not "live", the `live` method is just a very weird piece of (deprecated!) syntactic sugar. `live` attaches event handlers at the document level, so those event handlers always get attached, whether there are any matching elements or not. You shouldn't use `live` with the newest version of jQuery because it's confusing, prefer `$(document).on(...)`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: You're right; it sounds like he completely misunderstood my point.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: *"a very weird piece of (deprecated!) syntactic sugar"* Well said.

Comment: Hmm, intersting, I honestly had no idea how live worked other than I know it searched the document for elements after the page has loaded.  So to get this right, live adds the element in advance to the page.  Then, when the ajax event is called, it simply fills it in?  Additionally, if live is deprecated, what is the correct way to specify if the method should check for these "live" elements?  Thanks for the help everyone!  Very much appreciated! :)

Comment: @user1110302: `live` maintains a list of selectors and handlers.  It then handles that event for _all_ elements (via bubbling) and checks them against the handlers.  Use `.on()` or `.delegate()` instead.  See the documentation.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: `live` does not "look for elements" or "add elements in advance". It attaches a handler to the document level, listening to all events of the type that bubble up to it (look up event bubbling). Whenever an event is fired, it examines the source of the event to see if it matches the selector. Use the newest version of jQuery and `$(document).on("click", ".selector", func)` instead of `$(".selector").live("click", func)`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery always works on lists of elements. When the selector doesn't match anything, you get an empty list, and manipulating that does nothing.

Attaching events to nonexistent elements like doesn't actually do anything, so no, that's not leaking memory.

Answer (score 2):

the $() function will loop through the elements in the window. If #target found, then the onclick event will be added.

If it doesn't exist, then nothing will happen, you will get an empty jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

The result of the element not being present should be that it just isn't bound to anything and therefore clicking on something that isn't there will have no affect.

I would also like to point out that if the element is added in via ajax and you bound the '#target' element to a specific click function, like you did in the posted code, before the ajax call it will not function. In those cases you would use the '.live' binding function to guarantee that the function is bound to the element. Also Firefox is a memory hog, it is pretty common for its memory usage to grow crazy fast.

Answer (score -1):

The way I understand it, the $('#target') selector won't select anything, and so the click won't bind to any elements. It won't cause any memory issues or anything.